# Disable UIImageView resizing behavior when contentMode UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have `UIImageView` with `contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

I need this mode to display my image properly. **But also I need imageView cropping image when its frame changes like it was with** `UIViewContentModeTopLeft`.

How I can obtain this?

Edited:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
imageView.image = someImage;
```

Now I get this (and it's ok, image scaled properly and looks good):

[image]

Then, I have method:

```
- (void)setRating:(double)rating {
      double starWidth = imageView.image.size.width / _maxRating;
      CGRect oldFrame = self.frame;
      imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rating * starWidth, oldFrame.size.height);
      _rating = rating;
}
```

after this method I need to get something like that:

[image]

**BUT because of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` I get scaled image**

Comment: what do u want to get ??

Comment: edited. hope it will give some clarity

Comment: Besides being clever, what purpose is there to delay processing what appears to be basic assets until run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really get what you want from that imageView in the method you are attempting without a lot of extra work. When you resize the view you will see that scaling, that is the mode you set and thats really all that will happen.
There are a number of possibilities, many involve resizing things yourself thru subclassing. But as for solutions:

1. Size your art prior to runtime, and then you don't need to do the scaling for every display of those stars for every user and every run. Save the electrons!
2. Add the imageView as a subview to some other container view which you will match to the scaled size of the imageView, then resize to clip the imageView portion you do not want displayed.